# What ways can I change which enchantments the table gives me in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have decided to start a new survival world on my Minecraft Bedrock Edition and I have ran into an issue: I seem to not be able to get different enchantments.

While trying to enchant a Bow, it has only gave me the options of Power 1. That was not satisfactory, so I decided to put a better bow enchantment on a book.

Now the books is only offered Efficiency 1, Sharpness 1, and Impaling 1. I tried multiple books, putting the Bow in again, replacing my table, and placing a few book shelves around (sadly I don't have 15 shelves of yet).

**Is there any way to reset the random enchantments offered?** As far as I had read on Enchantment Tables are supposed to be random, but now I am unsure.

Thanks for the help in advance!

*Note: I am playing v1.4.0 on Windows 10*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As enchantments offered depend on the enchantment level and the enchantment level depends on the number of active bookshelves, an easy way to change the enchantments offered is to disable bookshelves by placing torches between them and the enchantment table. That way one can still have the entire 'ring' of bookshelves around the table but get lower-level enchantments. Breaking the torches will restore the effect of the bookshelves.

[Select an Enchantment level](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Enchanting_mechanics)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to more bookshelves giving better enchantments you will also get three new random enchantments every time you enchant something.  So if there are three options on a book and you don't like any of them you can pick the cheapest one and then put a new book in and you will have three more random options.  This also works for any enchant-able item it does not have to be only on a book.  Typically I use books because you can then store the enchantments in case you or someone else would want/need it later.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after adding more bookshelves, the enhancements listed change, so I am guessing the enchantments offered are determined by the item and the amount of bookshelves near it.

Comment: You’re right. See [the wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Enchantment_mechanics) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can add more bookshelves, or takes some out. The more bookshelves, the higher level enchantments the table will offer. However, mending, frost walker, and the curses are not available from tables. Also making an enchantment will reset all the enchantments to other random enchantments, so if you don't like what you are being offered, enchant something cheap like a stone pickaxe with the cheapest enchantment. Hope this info helps.

About the part of not having 15 bookshelves yet, here are a few suggestions. I don't know what biome you are in, but try to find a village. They are found in plains, desert, savanna, taiga (spruce forest), and snowy areas. Try to find a villager that will sell you bookshelves.